# How to allow multiselction in cell using streamlit with st_aggrid?

Tags: python-3.x, ag-grid, multi-select, streamlit

how to use the multiselect option inside cell in order to allow user to select multiple values and then display the selected values seperated with comma ??

i already work with single selection using the below configuration

```
gd.configure_column('source',width = 500,editable = True,cellEditor = 'agSelectCellEditor',cellEditorParams={"values":["source1","source2","source3"]})
```

the above configuration work perfect.
But now i want to display more than one source where the user can have multiple sources  how could the configuration be changed in order to meet my requirements ?

I will appreciate any help .